# ¿Cómo transformar cada grupo de un objeto DataFrameGroupBy de 2 claves o más a dataframes de manera automática?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Formularé la pregunta mediante un ejemplo, un groupby usando 2 claves:

```
double_group = data.groupby(["Gender", "Economic Status"])
```

Para este ejercicio el objeto double_group contiene 6 grupos, pero quiero convertir todos los grupos en 6 objetos distintos siendo todos dataframes (dataframe_grupo1, dataframe_grupo2...) de manera automática con una función o como sea.

```
len(double_group) #La salida es 6 porque hay 6 grupos o 6 combinaciones:
('Female', 'Middle Class'),
('Female', 'Poor'),
('Female', 'Rich'),
('Male', 'Middle Class'),
('Male', 'Poor'),
('Male', 'Rich')
```

Se que puedo usar esto pero no obtengo lo que busco:

```
for names, groups in grouped_gender:
  print(names)
  print(groups)
```

Por otro lado intenté usar el pandas.get_group, pero parece que no es posible usarlo después de agrupar por más de una clave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero de todo para explicarlo haré un ejemplo:

```
datos_filtrados = {"sexo":["mujer", "hombre"]*4,
                   "opinion": ["buena", "mala", "mala", "buena"]*2,
                   "producto":["chanclas", "camiseta", "zapato", "bañador", "abrigo", "sudadera", "pantalones", "camisa"],
                   "precio": range(8)}

df_productos = pd.DataFrame(datos_filtrados)
print(df_productos)
```

**Salida:**

```
sexo    opinion producto    precio
0   mujer   buena   chanclas    0
1   hombre  mala    camiseta    1
2   mujer   mala    zapato  2
3   hombre  buena   bañador 3
4   mujer   buena   abrigo  4
5   hombre  mala    sudadera    5
6   mujer   mala    pantalones  6
7   hombre  buena   camisa  7
```

Lo más sencillo es ir iterando y filtrado por cada tipo de valor. En este caso vamos a usar las columnas `sexo` y `opinion`

```
#Vemos los distintos valores de las distintas columnas
dif_sexo = df_productos["sexo"].drop_duplicates()
dif_opinon = df_productos["opinion"].drop_duplicates()

#Buscamos por los valores y guardamos cada `DataFrame`
dataframes_agrupados = []
for sexo in dif_sexo:
    for opinion in dif_opinon:
        dataframes_agrupados.append(df_productos[(df_productos["sexo"]==sexo) & (df_productos["opinion"]==opinion)])
```

Lo que hacemos aquí es:

1. Cogemos los valores distintos de las columnas `sexo` y `opinión` y nos creamos dos listas `dif_sexo` y `dif_opinion`
2. Nos creamos una lista vacía donde guardaremos los distintos `DataFrame`
3. Creamos tantos bucles `for` como columnas queramos combinar, en este caso son dos.
4. Utilizamos la sintaxis de filtrado de pandas, en la cual le decimos que filtre los `DataFrame` por `sexo` y `opinion`. `dataframes_agrupados.append(df_productos[(df_productos["sexo"]==sexo) & (df_productos["opinion"]==opinion)]`

### Usando get_group

> Por otro lado intenté usar el pandas.get_group, pero parece que no es posible usarlo después de agrupar por más de una clave.

Sí se puede, aunque para esta tarea me parece más tedioso, ya que no hay el porque utilizar el método `groupby`. Pero sería así:

```
df_productos_agrupados = df_productos.groupby(["sexo", "opinion"])

dif_sexo = df_productos["sexo"].drop_duplicates()
dif_opinon = df_productos["opinion"].drop_duplicates()

dataframes_agrupados = []
for sexo in dif_sexo:
    for opinion in dif_opinon:
        dataframes_agrupados.append(df_productos_agrupados.get_group((sexo, opinion)))
```

En el caso de que quieras usar el método `.get_group()` si se ha agrupado por varias columnas, es necesario **pasarle una tupla** con las columnas. Es decir: `.get_group((sexo, opinion))`

Comment: Muchas gracias @RubialesAlberto, las dos formas son muy buenas respuestas y dos formas distintas de lo que estaba acostumbrado hacer. Lo que estaba haciendo es hacer uso del get_group usando groupby previamente, usando tuplas y asignándolo a un objeto, pero con las soluciones dadas tengo la misma duda, hay forma de obtener los 4 dataframes de una sola vez en 4 objetos distintos?, las salidas de tus dos respuestas me da una lista pero de igual forma tendría que extraer manualmente cada grupo en un objeto dataframe diferente, uno por uno.

Comment: Perdona pero no entiendo lo que quieres decir, puedes explicar mejor a que te refieres con: *hay forma de obtener los 4 dataframes de una sola vez en 4 objetos distintos?*

Comment: Tu obtienes los 4 objetos `DataFrame`, y necesitas almacenarlos en agún sitio, si no lo almacenas, **se hace la operación y desaparece** puesto que no lo has guardado. En este caso los almacenas en una colección tipo `list`

Comment: Puedes no almacenarlos y hacer un `print()` directamente para que te salgan, pero no podrías operar más con esos objetos `DataFrame` puesto que no los has guardado. Si con *de foma automática 4 objetos* te refieres a almacenar 4 objetos sin indicarselo y sin usar una colección. NO, no hay forma alguna, si tu quieres poder consultar un objeto, este objeto tienes que existir en la memoria, si no es asignado a ninguna variable, o introducido en alguna colección, **el objeto no existe** y por tanto no puedes realizar ninguna operación con el.

Comment: Muchas gracias! entiendo, de todas formas en una buena opción iterar y luego guardarlos en una lista para posteriormente manipularlo, es una buena salida sin usar el groupby.